# templateUrl failed using angularJS with nodeJs..?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to fire up this mini app using templeUrl but I can't make it? :( This is the simple code, thanks for yr time!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <zippy>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    </zippy>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.directive('zippy', function(){
                return{
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: hello.html

                }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get in the console, what does it mean? My hello.html is inthe same folder like the index one.

```
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    at http://127.0.0.1:1339/index.html:24:34
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:27:173)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:36:469
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at n (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:6:192)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:36:438)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:28:127)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:29:298
    at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:26:479)
    at r (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js:46:142)
```

My node.Js code is very short:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
console.log('Starting');
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json'));
var host = config.host;
var port = config.port;
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){

        console.log('Receive request: '+ request.url);
        fs.readFile('public' + request.url, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404, {'Content-type' : 'text/plain'});
                response.end('SORRY DUDE');
            }else{
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
                response.end(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `templateUrl: 'hello.html'` instead?

Comment: @raina77ow yeah, but the page hangs up now?....the browser doesnt respond ....funny, dont get any misstake inthe console either..it's loading and loading and I can't close the tab?

Comment: Does `starting` show in console? `Receive request`?

Comment: @raina77ow thank you to put me in the right track! it's sorted! the problem was that my hello.html had a <html> and <body> tags. In other words I was trying to put one whole html page inside another....impossible right.. :)

Comment: u deserved a green mark sir! :)

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your Node code, you are doing...

```
  fs.readFile('public' + request.url)
```

might want to change it to:

```
  fs.readFile('public/' + request.url)
```

Comment: It doesn't complain on this but thank you; this is the proper syntax! By the way I fixed the problem. Pls read my comment (above)

Comment: Actually, it's misleading. The preceding `/` sign is a part of `request.url`, as shown [here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url). Who upvoted this, I wonder.